# do too many composer packages slow laravel apps?

Tags: laravel, performance, package

I have laravel project with a lot of packages and my composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "brozot/laravel-fcm": "^1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1",
        "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",
        "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "^4.2",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"

    },
```

will this slow my site ?

Comment: It's not the number of packages, it's how many register their own service provider which is something that will run on every single request. Classes from composer dependencies are autoloaded when needed so if the dependency doesn't register its own service provider then it will only be used when needed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not too much packages in your project. But make sure, that them are required to your project.

The question about speed of working your app is complicated, because perfomance is effected by many factors such a: database optimization, caching, project architecture, qualitty of your frontend and so on.

I recommend to you analyzing and tracking your website perfomance by [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). Here you can watch main metrics of your app like a time for page loading, size of current page, queries that have been done etc. And then you can understand, how some plugins or your own solutions effect on your perfomance.